Textbook for Feynman Diagrams
I need to get an understanding of Feynman diagrams, something I currently have basically no knowledge of, and I am looking for a good textbook/place to start. I have finished my 3rd year undergrad, and am very comfortable with the material in Griffith's Introduction to Quantum Mechanics, and Introduction to Electrodynamics. What is a good place to start?

Griffiths introduction to elementary particles physics is a good introduction to Feynman Diagrams. But if you want explicit derivation of the Feynman rules then you should use a QFT book like Peskin/Schroeder or Schwartz.

+1 for Peskin & Schroeder, made me understand Feynman rules after reading it just once. Really a great book, in other aspects as well.
